# Backbone-forms with custom Dust template

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, dust.js, backbone-forms

I'm having issues understanding how to display [customized backbone-forms](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-forms#example-fully-customise-forms-and-templates)  with [Dust.js template](http://www.dustjs.com/).

The relevant part of my code are here.

// Index.jx

```
<head>
    [...]
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/underscore.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/backbone-forms.js"></script>

</head>
```

// dashboard.dust

```
<div id="placeholderForm"></div
<section id="formTest">
           <form>
                  <h1>My Title here</h1>
                   <div data-editor="firstname,lastname,birthday"></div>
                   <hr>
                   <p>
                    some info
                    <div data-fields="address"></div>
                   </p>
                </form>
              </section>
```

// DahsboardView.js

```
const
    UserModel = require('../../models/user-model'),
    _ = require('underscore');

let View = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: require('./profile-dashboard.dust'),


    initialize: function () {
        let self = this;
        _.bindAll(this, "render");

        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
        this.model.fetch({ reset: true });
        console.log('model', this.model);


    this.profileForm = new Backbone.Form({
      template: this.template,
      model: this.model,
      validate: true
    });
        /*
        this.profileForm = new Backbone.Form({
        model: this.model,
        //template: _.template($('#formTest').html), //this.template,
        validate: true
        }).render();
        */
    },

    onRender: function() {
        console.log('render init');
        console.log('form', this.profileForm);
        let self = this;
        this.profileForm.render(); // Got problem here because template is not recognise as function or generally just not recognise as valid template
        $('#placeholder').append(this.profileForm.el);
        return this;
    }

});

module.exports = View;
```

I also try to render the form after appending the elements but no luck.

```
$('#userInfoForm').append(this.profileForm.render()el);
```

Errors are every time different but mostly are coming because `this.profileForm` is undefined when called in `render()` and from my understanding `this.profileForm` is undefined because `this.template` is not valid

Any ideas how to correctly communicate with backbone-forms?

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/designbygio/pen/JbgpZK?editors=1010) (not working but to show better the code)

Comment: include a [mcve].

Comment: thank for your comment @EmileBergeron. I added all the relevant part in my View and a codePen not working but at least show the code organized as mine.

Answer (score 0):

don't try and get the template from the DOM.. you have dust.

```
this.profileForm = new Backbone.Form({
  template: require('./profile-form.dust'),
  model: this.model,
  validate: true
});
```

also.. don't append the view manually.. backbone-form is a backbone view.. so just create it, add a region to your layout and

```
this.getRegion('formRegion').show(this.profileForm);
```